# Pycharm Package Install - offline

Tags: installation, pycharm, package, offline

Does anyone know how to manually add python packages to a pycharm project without any internet connection ?

Comment: do you have those packages in other virtual environments

Comment: Just in last year I started using PyCharm to install packages. So, you can still use the old way: install manually, with conda, pip, and all other virtual environment managers. You can still uses PyCharm as an editor and uses external tools from terminal.

Comment: @agam : No they are not in any other virtual environment. I have to begin with a fresh virtual environment.